# PDE bundle pool shall use Oomph bundle pool

Tags: eclipse, oomph

Oomph can speedup IDE installations due to its bundle pooling, such that artifacts already available can be reused by other installations. The documentation says

> Oomph's underlying infrastructure supports bundle pooling for all
>   aspects of the installation (and, optionally, even of the target
>   platform)

However, there is no documentation how this optional part can be realized, given a target described by a plain old .target file. PDE target resolution will resolve the contained bundles in `workspace\.metadata\...\org.eclipse.pde.core\.bundle_pool`, not in the Oomph based `%HOME%\.p2\bundle_pool`.

So how can one make an Oomph installation resolve target bundles in the Oomph bundle pool to gain benefits if the target definition is changing often?

Comment: At the moment, I'm not sure PDE allows to consume Oomph bundle pool. You may have to open a feature request on http://bugs.eclipse.org on this topic.